# yarn 2 (berry) doesn't use .yarnrc.yml from home directory

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I would like to use `npmAuthToken` from `.yarnrc.yml` which is located in my home directory

`~/.yarnrc.yml` content

```
npmScopes:
  company:
    npmAuthToken: NpmToken.token
```

`~/Project/MyProject/.yarnrc.yml` content

```
enableGlobalCache: true

logFilters:
  - code: YN0013
    level: discard

nodeLinker: node-modules

npmScopes:
  company:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmPublishRegistry: "https://company-url"
    npmRegistryServer: "https://company-url"

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-workspace-tools"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.0.cjs
```

However, when I try to run `yarn install` it fails on the resolution step with the following message: `Invalid authentication (as an anonymous user)`.
It worked fine with yarn 1 and `~/.npmrc` file. Now we're going to migrate yarn 2, but I stuck with this issue. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here, I can't use my private registry on GitHub after migration to Yarn 2

Answer (score -3):

You can include registry configuration directly into .yarnrn.yml file with

```yaml
npmRegistryServer: "<registry_url>"
npmAlwaysAuth: true
npmAuthIdent: "<authToken>"
```

Also with this config is enough, you won't need adding **npmScopes** property anymore.